# Specifying tile background color with Split Raster of ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

In ArcMap Desktop 10.2.2, I have a Erdas Imagine, please see the picture, its NoData is displayed as blue.
I can use "Split Raster" tool(Opened by clicking: menu Geoprocessing >> ArcToolBox >> Data Management Tools >> Raster >> Raster Processing >> Split Raster)  to split this map into tiles. 
however, in the splited tiles, the backgrond is black, (what I expect is background is blue).

How can I specify a color that nodata pixel will be rendered ?

I guess that the color may be related to the "NoData value" option when I runing "Split Raster", however, I searched all web but can not find any clues how to set this option.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

At last, we use the plugin "gridSplitter" in qgis to solve this.
basically, the "gridSplitter" plugin use gdalwarp to cut a tile from img,
it can specify two argument: srcnodata and dstnodata, in my img,
set srcnodata to 0, and dstnodata 100 to set background to gray.
if blue, set dstnodata to "0 0 255".